# Time Limit Exceeded in Merge Sort program

Tags: java, mergesort

I tried to implement Merge sort but I am getting Time Limit Exceeded error.
I tried this on GeeksForGeeks platform. The code is working fine for almost all test cases.
Is there any way to optimize the code?

This is my code:

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 
    int b[] = new int[n];
    
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = l;
    
    while (i <= m && j <= r) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            b[k] = arr[i]; 
            i++;
        } else {
            b[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    
    if (i > m) {
        while (j <= r) {
            b[k] = arr[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        } 
    } else {
        while(i <= m) {
            b[k] = arr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    for (k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        arr[k] = b[k];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l > r) {
        return;
    }
    
    if (l < r) {
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you find out *any* information about the test case(s) you fail on?

Comment: If you are looking for improvements to working code, the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask.

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to do a one time allocation of a second array, instead of allocating on every merge. This example does a one time copy, then alternates the direction of merge with each level of recursion to avoid copy back. mergeSort is the entry function, mergeSortR is the recursive function:

```
static void mergeSort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    r += 1;                             // change r to end (last+1)
    if((r-l) < 2)                       // return if nothing to sort
        return;
    int [] b = a;                       // one time copy
    mergeSortR(b, a, l, r);
}

static void mergeSortR(int b[], int a[], int bb, int ee)
{
    if ((ee - bb) == 1)                 // if one element, return
        return;
    int mm = (bb+ee)/2;                 // midpoint, start of right half
    mergeSortR(a, b, bb, mm);           // sort left  half of a to b
    mergeSortR(a, b, mm, ee);           // sort right half of a to b
    merge(b, a, bb, mm, ee);            // merge b to a
}

static void merge(int a[], int b[], int bb, int mm, int ee)
{
    int o = bb;                         // b[]       index
    int l = bb;                         // a[] left  index
    int r = mm;                         // a[] right index
    while(true){                        // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
            if(l < mm)                  //   if not end of left run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)               //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                      //     and return
        } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < mm)               //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                      //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `merge` function allocates a temporary array that has the full size of the original array at each step of the algorithm. The interpreter might be unable to optimize this and free the array immediately after each call, relying on the garbage collector to release the memory.

You can improve this algorithm by reducing the length of the array allocated for the merge:

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{ 
    int n = r - l + 1;
    int b[] = new int[n];
    
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = 0;
    
    while (i <= m && j <= r) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
            b[k++] = arr[i++]; 
        } else {
            b[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    
    if (i > m) {
        while (j <= r) {
            b[k++] = arr[j++];
        } 
    } else {
        while(i <= m) {
            b[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
    }
    
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        arr[l + k] = b[k];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
    }
}
```

You can further reduce the allocated space by only allocating a copy of the left part:

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{ 
    int n = m - l + 1;
    int b[] = new int[n];

    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = 0;

    while (i <= m) {
        b[k++] = arr[i++]
    }
    
    i = l;
    k = 0;
    
    while (k < n && j <= r) {
        if (b[k] <= arr[j]) {
            arr[i++] = b[k++]; 
        } else {
            arr[i++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (k < n) {
        arr[i++] = b[k++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, mid, r);
    }
}
```

An even more efficient version would allocate a single temporary array with a length half the length of the array to be sorted and pass this array as temporary storage to the recursive calls:

```
void merge2(int arr[], int l, int m, int r, int b[])
{ 
    int n = m - l + 1;
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = 0;

    while (i <= m) {
        b[k++] = arr[i++]
    }
    
    i = l;
    k = 0;
    
    while (k < n && j <= r) {
        if (b[k] <= arr[j]) {
            arr[i++] = b[k++]; 
        } else {
            arr[i++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (k < n) {
        arr[i++] = b[k++];
    }
}

void mergeSort2(int arr[], int l, int r, int b[])
{
    if (l < r) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort2(arr, l, mid, b);
        mergeSort2(arr, mid + 1, r, b);
        merge2(arr, l, mid, r, b);
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        int b[] = new int[(r - l) / 2 + 1];
        mergeSort2(arr, l, r, b);
    }
}
```